# How to apply on change event in angular xeditable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

Here is my view code where I need to apply on change event

```
<span editable-select="user.testtype" e-name="testtype" e-form="rowform" e-ng-options="s.id as s.type_name for s in testtypes">
{{ showTestType(user) }}
</span>
```

I tried `ng-change`, `e-ng-change` and also `onchange` inside span but these doesn't work.

Comment: We can apply ng-change event only on input filed see the official documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

Comment: @Rahul That's why Its not working mate. so what your suggestion to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

this is a snippet form the x-editble site

```js
var app = angular.module("app", ["xeditable", "ngMockE2E"]);

app.run(function(editableOptions) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $q, $http) {
  $scope.user = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'awesome user'
  };

  $scope.updateUser = function() {
    console.log(this.$data)
    return $http.post('/updateUser', $scope.user);
  };
});

// mock `/updateUser` request
app.run(function($httpBackend) {
  $httpBackend.whenPOST(/\/updateUser/).respond(function(method, url, data) {
    data = angular.fromJson(data);
    if(data.name === 'error') {
      return [500, 'Error message']; 
    } else {
      return [200, {status: 'ok'}]; 
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div[ng-app] { margin: 50px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/dist/js/xeditable.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/angular-mocks.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link href="http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/dist/css/xeditable.css"/>
<h4>Angular-xeditable Onaftersave (Bootstrap 3)</h4>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    
  <a href="#" editable-text="user.name" onaftersave="updateUser()">
    {{ user.name || 'empty' }}
  </a>
    
  <div style="margin-top: 30px">
  {{ user | json }}    
  </div>
    
</div>
```

look at `$scope.updateUser` function and this is you solution